# Getting failed to load resource error with DatePicker

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

Ii was trying with datepicker i'm getting error:

> :3000/app/common/basic.html:1 Failed to load resource: the server
>   responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> zone.js:665 Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load
>   app/common/basic.html ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
>   Failed to load app/common/basic.html undefined

datepicker.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';      
 @Component({
  selector: 'demo-datepicker-basic',
  templateUrl: './basic.html'
})
export class DemoDatepickerBasicComponent {}
```

datepicker.ts

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-4 form-group">
      <input type="text"
             placeholder="Datepicker"
             class="form-control"
             bsDatepicker>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-4 form-group">
      <input type="text"
             placeholder="Daterangepicker"
             class="form-control"
             bsDaterangepicker>
    </div>
  </div>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import{DemoDatepickerBasicComponent} from './common/datepicker'

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,DemoDatepickerBasicComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import{DemoDatepickerBasicComponent} from './common/datepicker'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1><demo-datepicker-basic></demo-datepicker-basic>`,
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

Comment: didn't got it properly please explain more?

Comment: I'm using angular 4, i'm trying to implement datepicker in my application,while using datepicker i'm getting error even i'm fallowing all the steps